# Grouping items in certain intervals and multiplying them with their associated values under another column in R

Tags: r

```
df_final %>% 
mutate(Temp_Zones = cut(max_temp, c(0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120))) 
%>% 
  group_by(Temp_Zones) %>% 
  summarize(X=n()) %>% 
  
 save(df_final, file = "df_final.RData")
```

So the code above groups the values under the ''max_temp'' column based on the parameter/degrees  (0-40-60-80-100-120) and next to it creates a column listing how many times each temp_zones have. The problem I have is with taking it to the next level:

Each temperature row has a quantity associated with it. For instance if the weather is 45 quantity on the same row is 200.

So imagine there are'40 to 60' Temp_zone has 108 observations. For all these 108 observations, for each row I would like to get each the matching Quantity data and then add them up (sum)

So my ultimate goal is to be able to see how many in total each temp group 40-60 //60-80 etc. has quantity wise.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try using `mutate(X = n())` instead of `summarize`. That way, each row of your original data frame will have its group count in the `X` column. You can then use this in further calculations before summarising the result.

Comment: This is very useful, now I have this new info in new columns.

 I have also got a 'Quantity' column and many observations there. for each row there is a value. For each value on Quantity column, I would like to sum them up based on the temp_zone group. 

So essentially, I would like to calculate --for the 40-60Temp zone the total quantity.

Comment: So you add `mutate(new_column = Quantity * X)`. It might be best to take a look at the [data wrangling cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) to get a basic idea of how  to do these things yourself. There is already a lot of information out there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well you're very nearly there.
One thing I strongly recommend, though perhaps I'm OCD, is that anytime you utilize `group` & `summarize` you always, always, always pipe into `ungroup()`. It will save a lot of time and confusion going forward.

In this instance,

```
df_final %>% 
    mutate(Temp_Zones = cut(max_temp, c(0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120))) %>% 
    group_by(Temp_Zones)                                           %>% 
    summarize(X=n())                                               %>% 
    # Ungroup releases the prior group_by command and allows for a return
    # to transformations.
    # group_by & summarize are for aggregations (like your n() )
    # and until you ungroup you will be in 'aggregation' mode even though
    # what you're really after here is a transformation* after an aggregation was applied
    ungroup()                                                      %>%
    mutate(desired_column = Temp_Zones * X)                        %>%
    save(df_final, file = "df_final.RData")
```

However, it is not entirely clear what you're after. It might make more sense for you to look into the difference between shallow and deep copies, though that theoretical knowledge is something R will do under the hood for you. This methodology would require making a copy of your current df, apply the aggregation (the count) and joining it back to the original. This seems very needlessly inefficient for how Im understanding this, but I think it might (...?) be what you need/be easier to understand.

Comment: df_final %>% 
    mutate(Temp_Zones = cut(max_temp, c(0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120))) %>% 
    group_by(Temp_Zones)                                           %>% 
    summarize(X=n(),
                        desired_column = X * max_temp) %>% ungroup() %>% save(.,file="df_final.RData")

Comment: My apologies my response was not articulating it well. 

So, to begin with my main 'df' has Quantity, Price and Weather Data columns.

My purpose is to:

Step 1-) Group the temperature intervals (such as 40-60 or 60-80 ie.
Step2-) The total quantity that each interval has (for this calculation what actually needs to be done is each row's quantity (for example 400pcs) needs to add up. 

I guess I need to use 'case_when' function for this. Something like if the value in max_temp column is above 40 and below 60, then take the value on the same row under quantity column and then sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have columns `Temp` and `Quantity` and you want the total quantity for each `Temp_Zone`. So, one row per `Temp_Zone`.

This uses `data.table`:

```
##
#   MRE: YOU should provide this
#        or, even better, your actual data...
#
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
df   <- data.frame(Temp=rnbinom(1000, mu=70, size=100), Quantity=rpois(1000, 30))
brks <- c(0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120)
##
#   you start here
#
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[
  , Temp_Zones:=cut(Temp, brks)][
  , .(.N, Quantity=sum(Quantity)), keyby=.(Temp_Zones)]
##    Temp_Zones   N Quantity
## 1:     (0,40]   2       67
## 2:    (40,60] 209     6219
## 3:    (60,80] 608    18561
## 4:   (80,100] 178     5354
## 5:  (100,120]   3       81
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. For me this retrieves how many observations there are for each temperature instead of the temp_zone though.

Comment: You'd have to share your data then. In this example `N` is the number of rows in each `Temp_Zone` and `Quantity` is the sum of the `Quantity` field for that `Temp_Zone`. For instance, on {0,40] there are 2 rows, with `Temp = (40, 39)` and `Quantity = (37, 30)`. So `N = 2` and `Quantity = 37+30 = 67`.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely poorly written code, but this one worked for me:

```
df_final_X <-  df_final %>%   
mutate(Temp_Zones = cut(max_temp, c(0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120))) %>% 
  group_by(Temp_Zones) %>% 
  mutate('0-40 Zone' = ifelse(max_temp <= 40, sum(Quantity), NA))%>% 
  mutate('40-60 Zone' = ifelse(max_temp > 40 & max_temp<60, sum(Quantity), NA))%>% 
  mutate('60-80 Zone' = ifelse(max_temp > 60 & max_temp<80, sum(Quantity), NA))%>% 
  mutate('80-100 Zone' = ifelse(max_temp > 80 & max_temp<100, sum(Quantity), NA))%>% 
  mutate('100+ Zone' = ifelse(max_temp > 100, sum(Quantity), NA))
```